In a Ghidra Java extension how can I achieve what the "Convert" context menu item does in the GUI?
In the Ghidra UI there is a "Convert" function on data that lets you change signedness, decimal vs hex, etc:

But I'm writing a Loader extension in Java and I can't seem to find the API that covers there. Where is it located?
